# npm install after window account name change

Tags: windows, npm, cmd, npm-install

I changed my account name and user directory name. (local but adminstrator also)

If I try to install npm packages in command prompt, the packages are downloaded under `C:\Users\{new account name}\` normally.
But if I try to install npm packages in command prompt as administrator, the packages are downloaded under `C:\Users\{old account name}\`

I changed npm config prefix and system variable. However, problems continue to arise.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The issue is most likely that you have not correctly changed the user profile when changing the user account name. You have a registry and very likely many configuration files containing strings and other data linking to a profile directory containing your previous user account name, and have not changed those. Please take a look at "Way 2" on [the following page](https://www.minitool.com/news/change-user-folder-name-windows-10.html), to find out the process you should have performed in order to change your account name, and the user profile directory together.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. I changed my account in the same way(Way 2). before I post the question. But this problem has occurred.

Comment: As I stated, not only does the registry need updating, _(now done)_, but all configuration files and settings may also require changing too! Even the majority of your %Path% variables may now be wrong, as they're likely usingf hardcoded directory paths, or other variables which have not been modified. The first thing I'd suggest is that you open your environment variables in the GUI, and change any user variables which point to your previous user name, e.g. `OneDrive`, `OneDriveConsumer`, `TEMP` and `TMP`. Then make sure to update that name in both the User and System PATH variables too.

Comment: You should probably also check that the other variables, like `APPDATA`, `HOMEPATH`, `LOCALAPPDATA`, `USERNAME` and `USERPROFILE` have been updated correctly too. Unfortunately, unless you search through your entire registry, and every configuration file on your system, you will not be able to modify everything, but then you'll learn in future not to change the profile directory name, or I suppose not to change your mind about the user account name on a pre-installed and previously logged in system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it going to "C:\Users[your username]\AppData\Roaming" and deleting 2 npm related directories, after that, I executed npm install on my project and it worked. I hope this works for you!